# Conditional pagebreak?

Tags: conditionals, page-breaking

Is there a way I can have LaTeX insert a pagebreak, if the last line of the page is a certain string? e.g.

```
\noindent \textsl{Solution}:
```

thanks very much!

Comment: Welcome to TeX & CO! I hope you enjoy your stay. Just remember: there's no need to sign your name, as your badge appears automatically on the lower right!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

For such cases I like to use the [`needspace`](http://ctan.org/pkg/needspace) package. It provides commands that request customizable amount of space left on the page, and if there's not enough space then a page break would be inserted.

You could define a macro:

```
\usepackage{needspace}
\newcommand*{\solution}{%
  \Needspace{2\baselineskip}%
  \noindent\textsl{Solution}:%
}
```

This will have the effect, that a page break would be inserted before "Solution" if this would be the last line on the page, like you desired. You may increase the value in the argument of `\Needspace` if more space seems more appropriate.

The package defines further command variants `\needspace` (a bit more relaxed regarding the space amount) and `\Needspace*`, which respects a `\flushbottom` configuration in contrary to the unstarred command `\Needspace`, which causes a ragged bottom.

In every case I recommend to create a macro `\solution` which you may use later in your document. The reason is logical formatting - if you later decide to use `\textbf` instead of `\textsl` or a command like `\section*` or `\subsection*`, you need to change just the macro definition, not the whole text.

Comment: this looks great! I ll try it today.. only the thing is, I've already written the whole thing, so it's a little late for writing a newcommand now. Also, does it matter that my solution line is between two \medskip's ?!

Comment: The `\medskip` commands make no big difference, the macro works the same. I just would request more space then, like `\Needspace{3\baselineskip}`. I guess search&replace of your editor would work, replacing all occurences of `\noindent \textsl{Solution}:` by `\solution`.

Comment: This will have massive (positive) impact on my latex editing.. It also works  within environments! thanks so much!