# How to prevent a page break inside a specific paragraph?

Tags: page-breaking

I have a two-line paragraph that I would like to keep on the same page:

> The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. He is 
>  very happy that he can jump so high.

Sadly, the paragraph occurs at a point in the document where it is split by a page break, and this looks bad:

> The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. He is 
>  ----------- Page Break ------------- 
>  very happy that he can jump so high.

Is there a way to keep this text on the same page? I tried putting `\begin{samepage} ... \end{samepage}` around this paragraph, but it has no effect on the output, the paragraph is still split across two pages. I also tried `\nopagebreak`, but again no effect. Are there any other options?

And just to be clear, this paragraph is not in an environment. It's simply text in the main body of the article.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You could just issue a `\pagebreak` at the start of the paragraph (to push it to the following page). Or, issue `\enlargethispage{\baselineskip}` before the paragraph to keep the last line on the current page.

Comment: `samepage` would work but you probably ended teh samepage enviornment before the paragraph ended so it did nothing. Please always show a small complete example document that shows the problem, it is hard to debug code we can not see.

Comment: Thanks, David! This is the answer exactly. I was able to get it to work with your suggestion!

Comment: Pretty similar to [page breaking - How can I tie two pieces of text together so LaTeX tries not to break exactly between them? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78226/how-can-i-tie-two-pieces-of-text-together-so-latex-tries-not-to-break-exactly-be/427848)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
\begin{samepage}
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. He is
very happy that he can jump so high.

\end{samepage}
```

Note you need the paragraph to end within the scope of the command.

Comment: Thank you, David! Yes, I was not putting enough space before \end{samepage}

Comment: It's not the space, it's the \par that a blank line turns into.