# Avoid single section heading on the bottom of the page

Tags: sectioning, page-breaking

How can i avoid a single heading (with just two or threee text lines) on the bottom of the page

I've used `needspace` package and added `\needspace{3\baselineskip}` before each heading, but I think that there is a  more rational (global) solution.

Edit: For more details I'm using Pandoc with Markdown and Latex.

```
\needspace{3\baselineskip}

##### Wartość komponentu $EXP$

Est tenetur et eveniet aut qui minima aperiam. Voluptatem numquam qui delectus aut aut fugit ut et. Nesciunt quam quidem quo officia laboriosam eveniet sapiente cumque. Ut repellendus laborum facere. Vero ut et similique omnis aut cumque.
```

This prevents situation where my "heading" remains on end of page in last line. My "header" was moved to new page (I want this situation by global):

[image]

instead of this situation:

[image]

Comment: Can you describe in more detail what you are trying to achieve? Do you want to avoid a page break if only three lines or less remain for the new page? What do you mean by header: Some section header oder the stuff that goes into the header area? Can you show the code that you tried, with the `needspace` package?

Comment: You can define your own header command and include `\needspace` in its definition. Is https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6233/110998 related?

Comment: @gernot I'm accustomed to headers from web development I mean subsubsections and more deeper elements.  I'm using Pandoc with Markdown and Latex, so I can add header `h3`, `h4`, `h5` by simple code like this `### Some text`, `#### Other text` and Pandoc generates to suitable subsections and strong texts. I would like to avoid situation where "header" created from `####` or `#####` remains at the end of the page if below this "header" would were rendered only three lines or less of texts. In other words I want to break page before "header" according to the lines of text.

Comment: But this happens automatically. This is one of the things that TeX takes care of: It never breaks after a section heading. Can you show the code of a document where the page break is not adequate? If you want to have more lines that stick with the heading than TeX does, adding `\needspace` to the definition of `\section` etc may help.

Comment: I've added more details to my question.

Comment: it looks like you have a blank line before the final display.  if you didn't, the display should not have started on a new page.