# parskip sometimes pagebreaks last line

Tags: line-breaking, page-breaking, parskip, paracol, columnbreak

I have a two-column spread, one column on even pages and the corresponding other on the facing odd pages, using `\begin{paracol}[1]*{2}` environments. But the package `parskip` randomly pagebreaks some of the odd pages' last line:

[image: MWE]

How do I fix this?

I tried some of the tips on "[Preventing page breaks between lines](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-nopagebrk)" but to no avail.

## MWE

The last `paracol` of the following as-minimal-as-I-can-get my working example exhibits my problem:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tocloft} 
\setlength{\cftbeforetoctitleskip}{0em}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3} 
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0} 
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage{parskip}


\usepackage{fontspec, newunicodechar}
\setmainfont{Nimbus Roman}
\newfontfamily{\fallbackfont}{Noto Serif}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textfallback}{\fallbackfont}
\newunicodechar{℣}{\textfallback{℣}}
\newunicodechar{℟}{\textfallback{℟}}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Nimbus Roman}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, linkcolor=black, citecolor=black, filecolor=black, urlcolor=black}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguages{latin}
\usepackage[top=0.25in, bottom=0.25in, left=0.25in, right=0.25in, nohead, heightrounded, includefoot, paperwidth=4.25in, paperheight=5.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{paracol}

\setdefaultlanguage{latin}
\setotherlanguages{english}
\newcommand{\latcol}[1]{\switchcolumn[0]*\textlatin{#1}}
\newcommand{\engcol}[1]{\switchcolumn[1]\textenglish{#1}}
\newcommand{\engtit}[1]{\switchcolumn[0]*\textenglish{#1}}

\title{Compilation \\ of \\ Mealtime Prayers \\ in \\ English and Latin}
\date{2023}


\makeatletter

\def\@endpart{} 

\patchcmd{\part}{\null\vfil}{}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}


\begin{titlepage}
    \begin{center}
        \Huge{Compilation of Mealtime Prayers in English and Latin}
        \vfill
        \includegraphics{image1.jpeg}
        \vfill
    \end{center}
\end{titlepage}

\relscale{1}

\sloppy
\raggedbottom

\tableofcontents

\part{Temporal Cycle Propers}
\pagebreak

\begin{paracol}[1]*{2}
    \engtit{\section{Advent Ferials}}
    \latcol{\emph{ante comestionem:}}
    \engcol{\emph{before eating:}}
    \latcol{℣. Veni ad liberandum nos, Domine, Deus virtutum.}
    \engcol{℣. Come to deliver us, O Lord God of hosts.}
    \latcol{℟. Ostende faciem tuam, et salvi erimus.}
    \engcol{℟. Show Thy face, and we shall be saved.}
    \latcol{℣. Gloria Patri, etc. ℟. Sicut erat, etc.}
    \engcol{℣. Glory be, etc. ℟. As it was, etc.}
    \latcol{\emph{post comestionem:}}
    \engcol{\emph{after eating:}}
    \latcol{℣. Ostende nobis, Domine, misericordiam tuam.}
    \engcol{℣. Show us, O Lord, thy mercy.}
    \latcol{℟. Et salutare tuum da nobis.}
    \engcol{℟. And grant us thy salvation.}
    \latcol{℣. Gloria Patri, etc. ℟. Sicut erat, etc.}
    \engcol{℣. Glory be, etc. ℟. As it was, etc.}
\end{paracol}

\begin{paracol}[1]*{2}
    \engtit{\section{Christmas Eve (December 24)}}
    \latcol{\emph{ante comestionem:}}
    \engcol{\emph{before eating:}}
    \latcol{℣. Hodie scietis quia venit Dominus.}
    \engcol{℣. This day you shall know that the Lord will come.}
    \latcol{℟. Et mane videbitis gloriam ejus.}
    \engcol{℟. And tomorrow you shall see His glory.}
    \latcol{℣. Gloria Patri, etc. ℟. Sicut erat, etc.}
    \engcol{℣. Glory be, etc. ℟. As it was, etc.}
    \latcol{\emph{post comestionem:}}
    \engcol{\emph{after eating:}}
    \latcol{℣. Crastina die delebitur iniquitas terræ.}
    \engcol{℣. Tomorrow the iniquity of the earth shall be blotted out.}
    \latcol{℟. Et regnabit super nos Salvator mundi.}
    \engcol{℟. And the Savior of the world shall reign over us.}
    \latcol{℣. Gloria Patri, etc. ℟. Sicut erat, etc.}
    \engcol{℣. Glory be, etc. ℟. As it was, etc.}
\end{paracol}

\begin{paracol}[1]*{2}
    \engtit{\section{Christmastide Ferials}}
    \latcol{\emph{ante comestionem:}}
    \engcol{\emph{before eating:}}
    \latcol{℣. Verbum caro factum est, alleluia.}
    \engcol{℣. The Word was made flesh, alleluia.}
    \latcol{℟. Et habitavit in nobis, alleluia.}
    \engcol{℟. And dwelt among us, alleluia.}
    \latcol{℣. Gloria Patri, etc. ℟. Sicut erat, etc.}
    \engcol{℣. Glory be, etc. ℟. As it was, etc.}
    \latcol{\emph{post comestionem:}}
    \engcol{\emph{after eating:}}
    \latcol{℣. Notum fecit Dominus, alleluia.}
    \engcol{℣. The Lord has made known, alleluia.}
    \latcol{℟. Salutare suum, alleluia.}
    \engcol{℟. His salvation, alleluia.}
    \latcol{℣. Gloria Patri, etc. ℟. Sicut erat, etc.}
    \engcol{℣. Glory be, etc. ℟. As it was, etc.}
\end{paracol}

\begin{paracol}[1]*{2}
    \engtit{\section{Holy Name (January 2)}}
    \latcol{\emph{ante comestionem:}}
    \engcol{\emph{before eating:}}
    \latcol{℣. Sit nomen Domini benedictum, alleluia.}
    \engcol{℣. Blessed be the name of the Lord, alleluia.}
    \latcol{℟. Ex hoc nunc et usque in sæculum, alleluia.}
    \engcol{℟. Henceforth, now and forever, alleluia.}
    \latcol{℣. Gloria Patri, etc. ℟. Sicut erat, etc.}
    \engcol{℣. Glory be, etc. ℟. As it was, etc.}
    \latcol{\emph{post comestionem:}}
    \engcol{\emph{after eating:}}
    \latcol{℣. Afferte Domino gloriam et honorem, alleluia.}
    \engcol{℣. Give unto the Lord glory and honor, alleluia.}
    \latcol{℟. Afferte Domino gloriam nomini ejus, alleluia.}
    \engcol{℟. Give unto the Lord the glory of his name, alleluia.}
    \latcol{℣. Gloria Patri, etc. ℟. Sicut erat, etc.}
    \engcol{℣. Glory be, etc. ℟. As it was, etc.}
\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

Not sure if this is related, but it produces lots of `Overfull \vbox (4.20001pt too high) has occurred while \output is active` warnings.

Comment: You need to provide a minimum working example demonstrating the issue.

Comment: parskip does not act randomly, if you showed an example someone could trace the page breaking. Are you sure that line would fit, it looks very tight from your image??

Comment: @User23456234 Done.

Comment: What document class are you using?  If I take a guess, I get a 7 page document, not a 37 page document like you've shown.

Comment: @Teepeemm Sorry for the typo. It's `\documentclass{book}` and should be 9 pages.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue by making there be only one large `paracol` environment (not several separate ones) in each `part` section. I still don't know why many `paracol` environments didn't work.

<sup>But now section headings sometimes appear at the bottom of a page instead of on the next page, but [this is a different issue](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/365717/36603) that can be fixed with `\needspace{3\baselineskip}`, yet when I use the `needspace` package, my original issue crops up again…
Update: I fixed it with `\pagebreak[0]` before each section, which suggests and does not force pagebreaking!  -tip: [TexFAQ.org](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-nopagebrk)</sup>